# I want to hide a specific node in QTreeView - C++ - QT

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

i want to hide a specific node in QTreeView.
For example i have a node called "Positions" in my QTreeView. I want to hide this node, so that the user can't see it by his name.
Is it possible? And if yes it is possible with the name or only with the index?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: i haven't code for that. I mean i have a qtreeview in QT and i want to hide some nodes of it. For example there is a node with the name "position". Is it possible to hide it with the name ?

Comment: Just show the code with which you create the QTreeView and add the nodes, to use it as a basis for my attempts to solve. Please read [ask] and check the [tour]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a `node` -- a row, a column?  I suspect you're actually looking for a custom [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) with suitable [`filterAcceptsRow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow) and/or [`filterAcceptsColumn`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsColumn) overrides.